# WP_Query 'post__in with CustomPost Type not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type in WordPress called event. There are several hundred posts of type event, but two examples have the IDs 760 and 1545.

This code works and returns a format list containing the correct single post:

```
    $args = array( 'p' => '760', 'post_type' => 'event' );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        $output .= '<ul class="postlist">';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()).'" id="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
            if ( $excerpt) {
                $output .= '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
            }
            $output .= '</li>';
        endwhile;
        $output .= '</ul>';


    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $output;
```

If I modify the query as the following examples, nothing is returned.None of these ammendments return anything:

```
    $args = array( 'post__in' => array('760','1545'), 'post_type' => 'event' );
    $args = array( 'post__in' => array('760'), 'post_type' => 'event' );
    $args = array( 'post__in' => array('760','1545'));
```

Note that the second ID does work correctly as follows so I have verified the posts exist and can be individually queried:

```
$args = array( 'p' => '1545', 'post_type' => 'event' );
```

So My question is this, can I Custom Post Type be used with post__in?  All the information I'm seeing on the internet suggest it should work OK. Greatful for any thoughts on this.

Comment: I think you should pass (int) in the array `array(760, 1545)`

Comment: Thanks for comment. Unfortunately passing ints doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason the posts I was querying were set to draft. This only seems to affect WP_Query when using post__in which does check the post has a published status

The query produced by WordPress when using post__in looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID IN (760,1545)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event'
AND (
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Where as the query produced for the 'p' argument looks like this, with no additional status filter:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID = 760
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```